# What would be the correct way to access and modify a server-side highscore file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, raspberry-pi

I am making a javascript game for my Raspberry PI web server as a school project.
I have the highscore chart as a JSON file. I'm updating it to the client with a getJSON call, which works.
How should i do the writing part when a new highscore is reached? I am learning about nodejs, ajax and websockets but have had problems finding information.

I would like to learn how to do that kind of thing securely without opening too many permissions in the PI.

Comment: If you have a node server running, all you need to do is use `fetch`/`$.post` to send a new highscore, then have your node backend read, parse, update and save the file. Doesn't require any permissions besides node being able to read and write the file.

Comment: Unrelated, but I wouldn't keep it in a file. Just put the file somewhere, set perms to the user running the web app, and use normal NodeJS file IO.

Comment: How do i give a node script it's own permissions?

Comment: Store all your scores in an array and use the sort algorithm that works best for what you are doing. Google, "sorting-algorithms, high to low, javascript" and you will get more info than you need, I use bubble sort. Don't Know if its the best, I just know it works well in many situations for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the current scores in an object server side.

Each time your client sends updated scores back to the server you could update this in-memory score object and then write it out to a file to persist it.

Here's an example that saves out the current scores to a file and then reloads that file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var currentScores = [
    {initials: 'JDH', score: 10000},
    {initials: 'HMH', score: 9000},
    {initials: 'DDE', score: 7000}
];

const ScoresFile = './scores.json';



function SaveScores(scores) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(scores);

    fs.writeFileSync(ScoresFile, jsonData);
}


function LoadScores() {
    var jsonData = fs.readFileSync(ScoresFile);
    var loadedScores = JSON.parse(jsonData);

    return loadedScores;
}

SaveScores(currentScores);
var a = LoadScores();
console.log(a);
```